# Why can a single word have more than one Kanji?

Tags: etymology

For example, うなずく has 3 Kanji as follows.

- 頷く
- 首肯く
- 肯く

Why can this single word have 3 Kanji?

Comment: Possibly related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30735/11589

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is related to how Kanji were taken from Chinese. See [this link](http://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/kanji-pronunciation.html) for more information.

As time passes, which Kanji are used commonly and for which connotations may change. For example I haven't seen "首肯く" commonly (it doesn't come up in the conversion list when I hit space bar), but "肯く" is more common.

Also, in some cases there may be subtle, or major, meaning differences between the various Kanji (攻める＝attack physically、責める=attack psychologically)

Comment: `頷く`, of course, is much more common than `肯く` or `首肯く`.  And kana is also commonly used, perhaps because none of these three ways of writing the word in kanji are listed on the [常用漢字表](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf).

Comment: Originally I had written 頷く but at the last minute changed it to 肯く for some reason (: But you are write 頷く is much more common.