# to see a doctor

Tags: translation, word-choice

I found two different translations for "going to see a doctor," and I was wondering which contexts you would use each in.

The first is 受診{じゅしん}する  which is defined on jisho.org as "having a medical examination; seeing a doctor​."

The other option I found on jisho was （医者に）見てもらう。My understanding of this is that a literal translation would be "I received the favor of (being seen by) a doctor."

The first translation makes sense in that it literally refers to the examination. However, if you wanted to say, "I'm going to see a doctor [at a specific time]" (like tomorrow, today, etc) which one of these phrases would you pick? How would this be different from indicating continuing care by saying "I am being seen by a doctor" (on a continuing basis)?

Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use both:

> - 明日(病院を)受診します。
> - 明日(医者に)見てもらいます。
> - (月に2回)皮膚科を受診しています。
> - (月に2回)皮膚科の先生に見てもらっています。

Difference:

- 受診 sounds relatively more objective and formal because it's a kango (See: [wago-and-kango](/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango)). But it's safe also in casual conversations.
- 受診 can take an institute name as a direct object.
- As you already know, てもらう carries some nuance of "receiving favor", but it's not an issue unless you dislike the doctor.

As an aside, 見る can be [replaced by 診る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30738/5010).

Comment: `As an aside, 見る can be replaced by 診る.`  Doesn't it *have* to be 診る?  I've never see it as 見る in this context.

Comment: @istrasci Yes, the majority of people use 診る in this sense, but I don't think 見る is wrong. Two dictionaries I checked say `（「診る」とも書く）`.

Comment: 「病院を」でもOKですか？「病院で」ではなく

Comment: @sazarando 病院で見てもらう is fine, but 病院で受診する sounds tautological and weird to me. 病院を受診する is fine, but 病院を見てもらう would mean "to have someone look at the hospital".

Comment: I found a Japaneses blog post about 病院を受診する　http://koko10.com/hospital_visit/

Answer (score 3):

It's like going against the premise of the question, but neither is the most popular expression people use to mean "visit a doctor to take medical treatment". We usually say 病院に行く or 医者に行く（お医者さんに行く）. For seeing a doctor constantly, we use [通う](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/45457/meaning/m0u/).

So:

> 3時に病院に行きます。
>   明日お医者さんに行きます。
>   毎月歯医者に通っています。 (歯医者 *dentist*)

Now,

- **見てもらう**
  Context-wise, this word is likely used when you are already focused on (care about) a specific symptom you have, such as "I have an unusual headache, so I'm going to see a doctor" or "I have a such-and-such chronic disease, so I must see the doctor every week". That's because it literally mean *have it seen (= diagnosed, treated)*.
- **受診する**
  Although it's a single word to mean "see a doctor", the term is not a very casual word, say, for a child to use. Of course, it is okay for whoever an adult to use it in conversation, just always sounds like "ophthalmologist" instead of "eye doctor" (I hope I didn't misspell).